# Importrange google sheet {}

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Why does this not work?

=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxx";"'ITA'!B:AF");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";"'ING'!B:AF")}

I'm trying to import from different sheets into one organizing all the info by rows. Even if I use query to eliminate the possible blank rows and to introduce some criteria, it does not work.
The problem persists when I try to concatenate multiple importrange formulas to import from different sheets.

If I use importrange just one time it works, but then when I put it within {} it gives me back VALUE! as an error

If someone could help me it would be nice

Thanks for your help

Comment: 1. First and foremost troubleshooting step is to try each importrange formula `separately` and make sure the data is being imported in rightfully. 2. Opening curly bracket is missing in the formula you pasted above. 3. also its bound to fail in general if one(or both) the sheets you are trying to stack has NO data et all, I mean like an empty dataset

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The imported ranges may be too large to grab at the same time and the function could be timing out.

**My advice would be to import each into their own tabs then create a 3rd tab where you pull the imported data from each tab together.**

*If you don’t want the sheet to be cluttered you can always hide those tabs and they’ll still populate your main sheet.*